# Are there cameras allowing shortcuts for manual exposure settings?

Tags: manual-mode, moon, multiple-exposure

I have been playing with the Multiple Exposures feature of Fujifilm X-T2 to take photos of nature views with the Moon in them. First you take a shot of the Moon with appropriate aperture, shutter speed and ISO (say f/10, 1/250 and 250), then the camera asks you to take second shot with exposure settings appropriate for everything else in the frame (say f/4, 1/2 and 2000). The camera combines the two shots resulting in something like this:

[image]

Now, the problem is that manually adjusting settings between the two shots takes 10-30 seconds (especially when using manual focus as automatic one only works for the Moon itself). This is enough for the Moon to move in the sky so that it does not perfectly fit in its bright spot on the second shot; I have to slightly adjust the camera position in attempt to mitigate the issue.

I am therefore wondering if it can be possible to switch between the two sets of settings instantly using pre-configured shortcuts. X-T2 allows you to assign various settings to quick menu items and function buttons, but none of them seems to allow specifying fixed aperture/speed/ISO combinations. The closest feature is ISO Auto Setting 1,2 and 3 where you specify default/max ISO and min speed but camera can still override those if it wants.

In a nut shell, the questions are:

1. Does Fujifilm X-T2 not allow shortcuts for manually fixed exposure settings, or do I simply not see how to set them up?
2. Are there any modern cameras allowing this?

Comment: What you are doing is known as HDR (high dynamic range). Google HDR photography. You may find alternative ways you can do it with the equipment you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is common on professional cameras that do *not* have direct dials for shutter-speed.

On Nikon cameras such as the D500, you can enable *Extended Photo Bank* to add selected exposure settings to be part of the *Photo Bank*. On the D500 and D5 which feature modeless exposure mode setting, the selection is of the bank is done in the menu. On cameras with a traditional mode dial, like on the D7500, there are *U* modes.

Pentax uses the same *U* scheme on the model dial and Canon works the same way with C modes. Each mode recalls most camera settings, including exposure parameters. On some Pentax you have a single *User* position on the dial that lets you choose between different banks which is still faster than setting exposure manually.

The Fuji X-T20 and X-A2 also have custom modes on their dial, simply labelled as *C*, like Canon. Your Fuji X-T2 and the X-Pro2 do not support this since they have dedicated dials for exposure parameters.

Comment: All Canon 1, 5, 6, and 7 -series cameras as well as the x0D series (with the possible exception of the 77D) also have "C" modes on the mode dial as well as direct dials for shutter speed in any of the P-Tv-Av-M modes. The 1-series does not have a mode dial, but there is a mode button that, when pressed and held, allows one to chose modes, including *Custom* modes, by rotating the main dial.

Comment: "_Fuji X-T2 and the X-Pro2 do not support this since they have dedicated dials for exposure parameters_" — such a shame! Good to know, cheers!

Answer (score 15):

I can't speak for all manufacturers, but can answer your point 2. Canon does.

Their higher end models on the top mode wheel (e.g. auto, P, aperture priority/shutter speed priority and manual etc), also have from one to three C modes. These allow you to register and save settings, be it shooting mode (manual, aperture priority etc) down to their relevant settings of shutter speed, ISO etc, focus modes shootings styles. Anything.

Then next time you want to use that mode, you just twiddle the wheel onto the top.

Nikon offers a smilar as ["U" modes](https://3.img-dpreview.com/files/p/articles/7148267499/images/modedial.jpeg).

Comment: Nikon offers this, too - as ["U"-modes](https://3.img-dpreview.com/files/p/articles/7148267499/images/modedial.jpeg).

Comment: @flolilolilo thanks, I expected they would, I shall update my answer.